# Can't map a Query String parameters to my JavaBean (using Spring 4 and Datatables)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datatables, javabeans

I'm really stuck into trying to map my QueryString parameters into my Spring JavaBean Command object here, and I couldn't find an answer to my question so far.

I'm using jQuery Datatables plugin with [server side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) so that each action in my datatable, triggers an AJAX request to my Spring application.

This is the parameters the Datatable plugin is sending to my Rest service:

```
http://localhost:8080/relatorios/produtos-source?draw=2&columns[0][data]=nome&columns[0][name]=&columns[0][searchable]=true&columns[0][orderable]=true&columns[0][search][value]=&columns[0][search][regex]=false&columns[1][data]=nomesAlternativos&columns[1][name]=&columns[1][searchable]=true&columns[1][orderable]=true&columns[1][search][value]=&columns[1][search][regex]=false&order[0][column]=2&order[0][dir]=asc&start=0&length=10&search[value]=ss&search[regex]=false&_=1400248561282
```

This is how I am receiving it in my Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/produtos-source", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public ProdutoTable dataTableRequest(@ModelAttribute DataTableCriterias criterias) {
    ...
}
```

And finally, this is my DataTableCriterias JavaBean (indicated by @ModelAttribute):

```
public class DataTableCriterias {
    private int draw;
    private int start;
    private int length;

    private Map<SearchCriterias, String> search;

    private List<Map<OrderCriterias, String>> order;

    private List<Column> columns;

    public enum SearchCriterias {
        value,
        regex
    }

    public enum OrderCriterias {
        column,
        dir
    }

    public class Column {
        private String data;
        private String name;
        private boolean searchable;
        private boolean orderable;
        private Map<SearchCriterias, String> search;
    }
}
```

*(get / setters ommited)*

This almost works perfectly! If I remove this line:

```
private List<Column> columns;
```

then Spring automagically populates my DataTableCriterias bean from the query string (but of course, I don't get the columns property mapped)

But with this line added, I get this error:

```
2014-05-16 17:20:16.605 ERROR 2368 --- [tomcat-http--99] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/relatorios] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'columns[0][data]' of bean class [com.bergermobile.rest.domain.DataTableCriterias]: Illegal attempt to get property 'columns' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'columns' of bean class [com.bergermobile.rest.domain.DataTableCriterias]: Could not instantiate property type [com.bergermobile.rest.domain.DataTableCriterias$Column] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.bergermobile.rest.domain.DataTableCriterias$Column] with root cause

org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'columns' of bean class [com.bergermobile.rest.domain.DataTableCriterias]: Could not instantiate property type [com.bergermobile.rest.domain.DataTableCriterias$Column] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.bergermobile.rest.domain.DataTableCriterias$Column
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.newValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:651)
```

As I see it, the main problem is that the 'column' parameter sent by the Datatable plugin is a bidimensional and sometimes also a tridimensional array:

```
columns[0][data]=nome
columns[0][search][regex]=false
```

So, it looks like my Bean was correct, but I get this error and now I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, so I ended up fixing this issue with slightly modifying the parameters sent to the server, to transform the two 3D array of columns into a 2D array. So:

```
columns[0][search][value]=myvalue
columns[0][search][regex]=false
```

ended up being:

```
columns[0][searchValue]=myvalue
columns[0][searchRegex]=false
```

This is how to do that in Databables:

```
$('#produtosTable').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        "url": "produtos-source",
        "data": function(data) {
            planify(data);  
        } 
    }
});

function planify(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.columns.length; i++) {
        column = data.columns[i];
        column.searchRegex = column.search.regex;
        column.searchValue = column.search.value;
        delete(column.search);
    }
}
```

This way I can receive those properties in my Model object using this field:

```
private List<Map<ColumnCriterias, String>> columns;
```

---

Just for reference, here is my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/produtos-source", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public ProdutoTable dataTableRequest(@ModelAttribute DataTableCriterias criterias) {
    ProdutoTable produtoTable = produtosService.findProdutos();
    produtoTable.setDraw(criterias.getDraw());
    return produtoTable;
}
```

and here is final my DataTableCriterias @ModelAttriute:

```
public class DataTableCriterias {
    private int draw;
    private int start;
    private int length;

    private Map<SearchCriterias, String> search;

    private List<Map<ColumnCriterias, String>> columns;

    private List<Map<OrderCriterias, String>> order;

    public enum SearchCriterias {
        value,
        regex
    }
    public enum OrderCriterias {
        column,
        dir
    }
    public enum ColumnCriterias {
        data,
        name,
        searchable,
        orderable,
        searchValue,
        searchRegex
    }
```

*(get/setters omitted)*

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late to the party, but this: https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables

is a lovely alternative to read your datatables input elegantly. Even if you dont want to use JPA, you can simply use the DataTablesInput and DataTablesOutput classes to read the input correctly. I also included jquery.spring-friendly.min.js which allowed Spring to easily read the variables that came in.

Thanks to https://github.com/darrachequesne for a nice elegant solution.

Comment: I'm using it and it's great. I was just wondering how can it be extended to include also a date range filter. I'm new to DataTables and the tricky part for me is adding two custom params (dateFrom, dateTo) to the ajax request. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You send `columns[0]` as parameter, but `columns` has no entry with the index 0. In fact it has no entry at all as it is null.

You have to instantiate the list in the constructor of `DataTableCriterias` in order to make this work. And it has to have enough entries for the parameters you send.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't  understand. columns[0] does have an entry, which is:
columns[0][data]=nome
columns[0][search][regex]=false
Anyway, I have tried to add this constructor to my DataTableCriterias class:
public DataTableCriterias() {
  columns = new ArrayList<Column>();
 }
But still no luck
(the class in being automatically instantiated by Spring as I receive it as a @ModelAttribute in my Controller)

Comment: @Berger `DataTableCriterias.columns` is `null`. It can't have entries.