# I want to use DataTables column search. But I don't know how should be server side code

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, spring-mvc, datatable

I use this code for column search https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html
I use Spring MVC so I've contoller class. I get data from MongoDB. My question is how should be controller class?
This is my Javascript code:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {"url": "locations/pagedList", "type": "GET"},
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": false,
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "id", "visible": false},
                   // .........
                   ],
                   "initComplete": function () {

                    //for search
                    var column = this.api().column(7);

                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                        .on('change', function () {

                            column
                                .search($(this).val())
                                .draw();
                        });

                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });
```

```
And this is my controller side:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/pagedList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public LocationListResponse pagination(@RequestBody int draw,
                                           @RequestBody DataColumns[] columns,
                                           @RequestBody int start,
                                           @RequestBody int length,
                                           @RequestBody Search search) { //... }
```

I see request in browser like this:

```
columns[0][data]=
columns[0][name]=
columns[0][orderable]=false
columns[0][search][regex]=false
columns[0][search][value]=
columns[0][searchable]=true
columns[1][data]=
columns[1][name]=
columns[1][orderable]=false
columns[1][search][regex]=false
columns[1][search][value]=
columns[1][searchable]=true
order[0][column]=4
order[0][dir]=desc
order[1][column]=4
order[1][dir]=desc
search[regex]=false
search[value]=
```

So I found this site about this: [DataStructure for the DataTable server side processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568446/datastructure-for-the-datatable-server-side-processing)

I'm getting this error: 400 Bad Request

Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. First we should change and add some attributes in javascript:

```
"ajax": {
                    "url": "locations/pagedList",
                    "type": "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    "contentType": "application/json",
                    "data": function ( d ) {
                        return JSON.stringify( d );
                    }
```

Second we should change controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pagedList", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public LocationListResponse pagination(@RequestBody JsonNode data) {
```

Thats it :)