# Handle Data table request parameters in spring request

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, datatables

I want to use jquery datatable in my project. I am able to hit ajax query and get json response for showing data in the table. But for using server side search and sorting, I need to accept the request parameters sent by datatable. The request parameters are in following form

```
draw:1
columns[0][data]:firstName
columns[0][name]:
columns[0][searchable]:true
columns[0][orderable]:true
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:lastName
columns[1][name]:
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
columns[2][data]:age
columns[2][name]:
columns[2][searchable]:true
columns[2][orderable]:true
columns[2][search][value]:
columns[2][search][regex]:false
order[0][column]:0
order[0][dir]:asc
start:0
length:10
search[value]:
search[regex]:false
```

I want to create a DTO object to accept this kind of request parameters. I have created following DTO.

```
public class DataTableRequestDTO {

    private int draw;
    private List<HashMap<String, String>> columns;
    private List<HashMap<String, String>> order;
    private int start;
    private int length;

    public int getDraw() {
        return draw;
    }
    public void setDraw(int draw) {
        this.draw = draw;
    }
    public List<HashMap<String, String>> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }
    public void setColumns(List<HashMap<String, String>> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }
    public List<HashMap<String, String>> getOrder() {
        return order;
    }
    public void setOrder(List<HashMap<String, String>> order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
    public int getStart() {
        return start;
    }
    public void setStart(int start) {
        this.start = start;
    }
    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

}
```

But when I hit the ajax url I get following error

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'columns[0][search][regex]' of bean class [demo.objects.DataTableRequestDTO]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'columns[0][search][regex]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [false]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1058)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:927)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:749)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

String is not valid datatype for handling columns[0][search][regex]. Please how to handle such kind of request in DTO object.

Thanks

Comment: Please see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704352/cant-map-a-query-string-parameters-to-my-javabean-using-spring-4-and-datatable/38834908#38834908 for a nice elegant solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23727596/4600335) post. I added

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        "url": "url",
        "data": function(data) {
            planify(data);  
        } 
    }
});
function planify(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.columns.length; i++) {
        column = data.columns[i];
        column.searchRegex = column.search.regex;
        column.searchValue = column.search.value;
        delete(column.search);
    }
}
```

In javascript and it converted

```
columns[0][search][value]=myvalue
columns[0][search][regex]=false
```

to

```
columns[0][searchValue]=myvalue
columns[0][searchRegex]=false
```

Now I can handle these request objects like

```
public class DataTableRequestDTO {

    private int draw;
    private List<HashMap<String, String>> columns;
    private List<HashMap<String, String>> order;
    private int start;
    private int length;

    public int getDraw() {
        return draw;
    }
    public void setDraw(int draw) {
        this.draw = draw;
    }
    public List<HashMap<String, String>> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }
    public void setColumns(List<HashMap<String, String>> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }
    public List<HashMap<String, String>> getOrder() {
        return order;
    }
    public void setOrder(List<HashMap<String, String>> order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
    public int getStart() {
        return start;
    }
    public void setStart(int start) {
        this.start = start;
    }
    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone..

Comment: Thanks for the grate solution. The only thing that I will add is the way the springMVC method must look like : the DataTableRequestDTO  must be an input of the method in the controller and should NOT be annotated with @RequestParam