# @ModelAttribute - binding properties in brackets instead of separated by dots

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

@ModelAttribute can bind `myObj.myProp` to the following class without issue:

```
public class MyObj {

   private String myProp;
   // plus a default constructor and setter / getter for myProp
}
```

But if the parameter is passed as `myObj[myProp]` it fails to bind. Can Spring bind properties specified within brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, spring is designed to interpret the attributes with `.` so it would work as `myObj.myProp`.

Comment: I'm using a UI library that passes the HTTP params using the bracket notation. Unfortunately, I cannot change to use dot notation. Since Spring errors with `org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException`, I'll have to get the param through the `HttpServletRequest` object. I did find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704352/cant-map-a-query-string-parameters-to-my-javabean-using-spring-4-and-datatable)  but not sure how they got Spring binding to work with brackets.